# DC Motor Speed and Current

Tags: voltage, current, motor, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor

I have a question regarding DC motor.

I was just curious to read on what factors does the motor RPM depend upon. I read that the rated voltage is the parameter that defines the speed of the motor.

But isn't current a defining factor?

I have 2 related questions:

1. I understand that since motor is just a bunch of coils (low resistance), the current through it would be more as the coils are low resistance. Am I correct? Is there any way to calculate the current through the motor coils?
2. Can someone explain with a little more intuition on how applied voltage determines the motor speed rather than the current through the motor coils?

Is the above answer same for DC motor and stepper motor as well?

Comment: Kind of a broad question.  Google "back EMF motor" and you can see why the back EMF limits the speed for a given excitation voltage.  You can look for an equivalent model to show how to calculate the current. Then maybe come back and ask any specific question you have.

Comment: Motor speed depends on the load also. Higher the load, lower the speed.

Comment: For a simple DC motor voltage is proportional to the speed, current is proportional to the torque. If the load is high, the motor will draw more current to maintain the speed set by the voltage. If the supply cannot provide such a current, the voltatge will drop and the speed will reduce. Or the motor will burn if not rated for such a current.

Answer (score 1):

This question has multiple points and is very broad, so it might get closed on that account.

In case it doesn't, here are some simple answers to the direct questions, which might send you in a helpful direction for self-study:

> I read that the Rated Voltage is the parameter that defines the speed of the motor.

Yes, but that's for any one particular motor:

You could apply the same voltage to two different motors and they might spin at different speeds.

You can apply two different voltages to the same motor, and it will spin at a different speed for each voltage.

> But isn't current a defining factor?

Yes, and current changes with applied voltage.  It also changes with output power, which is proportional to both [speed and torque](https://www.motioncontroltips.com/torque-equation/).

> I understand like, since motor is just a bunch of coils (low
> resistance), the current through it would be more as the coils are low
> resistance. Am I correct?

The current would be more *than what*?

Yes it's coils of wire, but they're arranged in a specific geometry and switched (commutated) through brushes or electronics so that they do mechanical work. The resistance of the wire is important, but that's not what makes it a motor.

> Can someone explain with a little more intuition on how applied
> voltage determines the motor speed rather than the current through the
> motor coils?

I'm sure someone *can*, but StackExchange may not be the best place to find that someone. Also, it's not an either/or situation with the effect of voltage or current.  They're both involved in a system that also includes the mechanical properties of the motor and whatever it's driving.

> Is the above answer same for DC Motor and Stepper Motor as well?

No.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain with a little more intuition on how applied voltage determines the motor speed rather than the current through the motor coils?

Any permanent-magnet motor (DC, brushless DC, or brushless AC) is also a generator.  It generates a voltage that's proportional to the motor speed times a constant that depends on the magnetic field intensity, the number of turns of wire in the coils, and the geometry of the motor.

When a motor is turning, this generator effect is also active, and the generated voltage is in opposition to the applied voltage.  It's called back EMF*.  If you had a perfect motor with either no friction or no resistance in the coil windings, the motor would spin up until the back EMF exactly equaled the applied voltage.

> I read that the rated voltage is the parameter that defines the speed of the motor.

Well, no.  If you know the motor's voltage/speed constant, and it's a typical motor, then when it's running unleaded its speed is pretty close to the applied voltage by the voltage/speed constant.  Basically, unloaded it acts a lot like an ideal motor.

> Is there any way to calculate the current through the motor coils?

Yes.  You need to start with the motor speed, the motor's speed/voltage constant, and the applied voltage.

So, calculate the back EMF: \$v_a = \omega_a k_t\$, where \$\omega_a\$ is the armature speed in radians per second, and \$k_t\$ is the voltage/speed** constant.

The effective voltage on the coils is the terminal voltage less the back EMF.  So you use that and Ohm's law to find the current: $$i_a = \frac{v_t - v_a}{R_a}$$

> Is the above answer same for DC motor and stepper motor as well?

Not really.  A stepper motor does generate back-EMF, and there is a lot of overlap between it and a DC motor.  But basically a stepper motor goes at the step rate, until the torque it needs is greater than the torque it can supply -- then it slips, and you say bad words.

* "EMF" = "electro-motive force", which is the "correct" term for "voltage".

** I'm using the symbol for the torque / current constant, because in an ideal motor they're the same, and I'm lazy.

Answer (score 0):

> I read that the rated voltage is the parameter that defines the speed
> of the motor.

That's correct.

> But isn't current a defining factor?

It is about the torque, not the speed.

> I understand that since motor is just a bunch of coils (low
> resistance), the current through it would be more as the coils are low
> resistance. Am I correct? Is there any way to calculate the current

Definitely not correct, it's a common wrong interpretation from many people that start to learn about motors. Imagine that we have a perfect super motor, no friction, no eddy current loss, made with superconducting material. It would run splendid. An electrical machine converts electric power to mechanical power and vice versa by use of EM field. The coil resistance generates heat - a pure loss, nothing useful.

> Can someone explain with a little more intuition on how applied
> voltage determines the motor speed rather than the current through the
> motor coils?

An electrical machine has a dual nature, at any time both motoring and generating modes are present. If you spin the generator faster, you get higher voltage - does this make sense? So, the final speed of the motor is the one when applied voltage equals to generated voltage, so no current can't flow. Current = torque = acceleration. No more current = no more acceleration = steady state.

Answer (score 0):

Voltage is the main variable that effects the speed of a motor. if you have 20 gigavolts your motor will explode (more like burn) if you have 1 volt your motor will spin very slowly. If you have a low current, it won't affect your motor as dramatically as voltage. For now the main thing you'll want to worry about in adjusting the speed of your motor is the voltage running through it.